# Loop help for 3D vector C++

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I'm trying to take an input file of variable length like this:

```
xxooo##xx
xoxxxoxoo
xxx#oxoo#
oxxxoxoox
xxoooo#xx
```

And turn it into a 3D char vector where each line is a 3x3 box with the first three characters being the first row, the next three the 2nd row, and the last three the 3rd row. For example the first row of the input should turn into this:

```
x x o
o o #
# x x
```

This is my attempt at a solution, but I get a segmentation fault when I try to run it. I'm new at C++ so this is my first attempt at a 3D vector and I don't have any clear error message to continue with, so I'm a bit stuck.

```
vector<vector<vector<char> > > makeBoard(vector<string> iflines)
{// Function to fill game boards from input strings

vector<vector<vector<char> > > charboard;

for (int i = 0; i != iflines.size(); i++) 
{   
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j=j+3)
    {
        charboard[i][j/3][0] = iflines[i][j]; 
        charboard[i][j/3][1] = iflines[i][j+1];
        charboard[i][j/3][2] = iflines[i][j+2];     
    }   
}
    return charboard;
}
```

Comment: You're indexing into `charboard` which is empty; you have to initialize it first.

Comment: How do I do that if I'm not sure how long it will need to be? I'm new to vectors, but I thought the whole point was you could add as you go

Comment: @AustinMW Your loops have end conditions, so yes you know how long it will be. And yes you can add as you go, but youre not adding (push_back) youre indexing directly into it.

Comment: Hmm i only know 2 out of the 3 dimensions beforehand, I tried doing push_back() but it said it didn't work for char type

Comment: use `vector::push_back()`. You can't directly write to an element via index `[]` until it's been created. See also `vector::reserve()`.

Comment: Alternatively, replace this with a 1D vector, and calculate linear offsets manually. 2D and 3D array syntax is ridiculous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<vector<vector<char> > > makeBoard(vector<string> iflines)
{// Function to fill game boards from input strings

    vector<vector<vector<char> > > charboard;

    for (int i = 0; i != iflines.size(); i++) 
    {   
        vector<vector<char> > line(3, vector<char>(3));
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; ++j)
        {
            line[j / 3][j % 3] = iflines[i][j];
        }
        charboard.push_back(line);
    }
    return charboard;
}
```

For each element of `iflines`, `line` is initialized to be a 3x3 vector of vector of char. It's filled in the loop and pushed to the back of `charboard`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, one line initialization could be like

```
vector<vector<vector<char> > > charboard(3, vector<vector<char> >(3, vector<char>(3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing elements of `charboard` by index but you have not initialized it yet.

You could use `push_back` but you know the size of the vector so it is probably a good idea to initialize it to the correct size upfront. The outer dimension is `iflines.size()`. The inner two dimensions are 3 and 3. As these are small and known at compile time it might be worth using something with a fixed size like `array` for the inner type:

```
using Board = std::array<std::array<char, 3>, 3>;
```

Then you can write:

```
std::vector<Board> makeBoard(const std::vector<std::string>& iflines)
{
  std::vector<Board> charboard(iflines.size());

  for (int i = 0; i != iflines.size(); i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j != 9; ++j)
    {
      charboard[i][j / 3][j % 3] = iflines[i][j];
    }
  }
  return charboard;
}
```